# What's the behavioral difference between HTTP Keep-Alive and Websockets?

Tags: http, websocket

I've been working with websockets lately in detail. Created my own server and there's a [public demo](http://isr.nu/ws/WebSocketTest.htm). I don't have such detailed experience or knowledge re: http. (Although since websocket requests are upgraded http requests, I have some.)

On my end, the server reports details of each hit. Among them are a bunch of http keep-alive requests. My server doesn't handle them because they're not websocket requests. But it got my curiosity up.

The whole big thing about websockets is that the connection stays alive. Then you can pass messages in both directions (simultaneously even). I've read that the Keep-Alive HTTP connection is a relatively new development (I don't know how many years in people time, just that it's only included in the latest standard - 1.1 - is that actually old now?)

I guess I can assume that there's a behavioral difference between the two or there would have been no reason for a websocket standard? What's the difference?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

A Keep Alive HTTP header since HTTP 1.0, which is used to indicate a HTTP client would like to maintain a persistent connection with HTTP server. The main objects is to eliminate the needs for opening TCP connection for each HTTP request. However, while there is a persistent connection open, the protocol for communication between client and server is still following the basic HTTP request/response pattern. In other word, server side can't push data to client.

WebSocket is completely different mechanism, which is used to setup a persistent, full-duplex connection. With this full-duplex connection, server side can push data to client and client should be expected to process data from server side at any time.

Quoting corresponding entries on Wikipedia for reference:
1) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection
2) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: OK. That exactly pushes my button. HTTP is still request/response even with a stay-alive connection. Websockets Rock!

Comment: Why did not they added a capability/ a header maybe of HTTP itself which would have made it behave like a native TCP connection, in which any party (sender/reciever) can send anytime any number of times?  Have they introduced a new Protocol WebSocket infact! just to achive this, "HTTP on Steroids" using upgrade option , once Initial handshake(TCP) is set using normal HTTP mechanism ?

Comment: The committee initially started off as an HTTP committee but what the WebSocket people wanted was too different and they decided to split. The WebSocket protocol handshake does start with an HTTP request, with an "Upgrade" parameter set to "Websocket".

Comment: Where you said "The main objects is to eliminate..", did you mean "The main objective is to eliminate..."?

Comment: But since it is a persistent connection, does that not mean that you can still send what ever, even if data does not match HTTP protocol's format?

Answer (score 9):

You should read up on [COMET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)), a design pattern which shows the limits of HTTP Keep-Alive. Keep-Alive is over 12 years old now, so it's not a new feature of HTTP. The problem is that it's not sufficient; the client and server cannot communicate in a truly asynchronous manner. The client must always use a "hanging" request in order to get a message back from the server; the server may not just send a message to the client at any time it wants.

Answer (score 9):

**HTTP vs Websockets**

**REST (HTTP)**

- Resources benefit from caching when the representation of a resource changes rarely or multiple clients are expected to retrieve the resource.
- HTTP methods have well-known idempotency and safety properties. A request is “idempotent” if it can be issued multiple times without resulting in unique outcomes.
- The HTTP design allows for responses to describe errors with the request, with the resource, or to provide nuanced status information to differentiate between success scenarios.
- Have request and response functionality.
- HTTP v1.1 may allow multiple requests to reuse a single connection, there will generally be small timeout periods intended to control resource consumption.

**You might be using HTTP incorrectly if…**

- Your design relies on a client polling the service often, without the user taking action.
- Your design requires frequent service calls to send small messages.
- The client needs to quickly react to a change to a resource, and it cannot predict when the change will occur.
- The resulting design is cost-prohibitive. Ask yourself: Is a WebSocket solution substantially less effort to design, implement, test, and operate?

**WebSockets**

- WebSocket design does not allow explicit or transparent proxies to cache messages, which can degrade client performance.
- WebSocket protocol offers support only for error scenarios affecting the establishment of the connection. Once the connection is established and messages are exchanged, any additional error scenarios must be addressed in the messaging layer design, but WebSockets allow for a higher amount of efficiency compared to REST because they do not require the HTTP request/response overhead for each message sent and received.
- When a client needs to react quickly to a change (especially one it cannot predict), a WebSocket may be best.
- This makes the protocol well suited to “fire and forget” messaging scenarios and poorly suited for transactional requirements.
- WebSockets were designed specifically for long-lived connection scenarios, they avoid the overhead of establishing connections and sending HTTP request/response headers, resulting in a significant performance boost

**You might be using WebSockets incorrectly if..**

- The connection is used only for a very small number of events, or a very small amount of time, and the client does not - need to quickly react to the events.
- Your feature requires multiple WebSockets to be open to the same service at once.
- Your feature opens a WebSocket, sends messages, then closes it—then repeats the process later.
- You’re re-implementing a request/response pattern within the messaging layer.
- The resulting design is cost-prohibitive. Ask yourself: Is a HTTP solution substantially less effort to design, implement, test, and operate?

Ref: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/14/when-to-use-a-http-call-instead-of-a-websocket-or-http-2-0/